# how to accomplish boxee.tv sliding video effect

Tags: jquery, video, effects, boxee

I was wondering if there is a jQuery plugin to recreate the "boxee.tv video effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at [jQuery Tools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/index.html) plugin and look at "Scrollable"

Comment: I just joined the Boxee revolution and saw the interface I think you're looking for.  Scrollable would probably be your best candidate.  It's easy to use and super configurable.  BTW, Boxee rocks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the boxee.tv video effect looks like, but maybe the jQuery UI Slider might be what you need:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/